# How to send welcome message to user using a chatbot developed with DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building a chatbot using DialogFlow. I want the bot to send a welcome message as soon as the webpage is opened.

I have read about it at : https://dialogflow.com/docs/events that Events can help in doing so but I don't know how to proceed further.

There is this command : 
{curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
"https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910&e=event_name&timezone=Europe/Paris&lang=en&sessionId=1234567890"}

but I don't know how and where to use this command. How is it related to my webpage ?

A practical example will be really helpful.

Comment: How are you integrating the bot into your website?

Comment: @gmolau I have embed an iframe with the html page.

Comment: If you are using the [Dialogflow Web Demo](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/web-demo) there is no way to make the bot interact with the web site (i.e. trigger an event when the page loaded or something similar). The command that you posted (see [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) on Wikipedia) does trigger an event, but does so in it's own session. If you would trigger that from your website it would have no connection to the bot in the iFrame, because that launches it's own sessions.

Comment: @gmolau Thanks for putting the light. Trying to search other ways on how to make it more interactive.